# CSS for tight (transparent) box around text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate this photoshopped header using CSS:

[image: Photoshopped header example]

I am doing this by creating a CSS class whose background is the header image:

```
.header-text {
  background-image: url(/images/group.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: auto;
  width: 900px;
  height: 250px;
  /*margin: 0px 0 0 0px;*/
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

And then putting an `h1` containing the text within the `div` of that class. Here's the CSS for the `h1` (sorry, it's excessively verbose since I've been trying to debug):

```
.header-text h1{
  background: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7),
      rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7)
    );
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: normal;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 900px;
  height: 82px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

And the HTML for the header:

```
<div id="header_wrap" class="inner">
  <div class="header-text">
    <h1>CS Women UMass Amherst</h1>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

However, no matter how hard I try I can't seem to get the text background flesh with the text as in the Photoshopped image. As far as I can tell I've removed all padding so I do not know where this extra background is coming from. The closest I've been able to get is the following:

[image]

Apologies in advance: I am not a front-end person!

Comment: Try `line-height: 1` on the text element.

Comment: @Rudie `line-height` seems to be the solution (somewhere else `line-height` was being set to 1.5) reducing `line-height` to about .75 gives me the result that I want. Please post as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative `line-height` should help get the effect I think you're looking for. Here's an [example](https://jsbin.com/zolayaz/edit?css,output).

Comment: `Line-height` is correct, though more appropriately, a `line-height` value of less than 1, as opposed to a negative value. "Negative values are illegal" http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

Comment: Correct, I should have said less than one.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `h1` is inside of the `<div class="header-text">` I would have written the CSS as this:

```
.header-text > h1 {
   ... all the css ..
}
```

instead of this (what you're doing):

```
.header-text h1 {
   ... all the css ..
}
```

I don't know if this is your problem, but it's a good tip anyway. It would be nice if you had a code snippet possible to run, so that your problem becomes clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I have very little experience with web development!

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting height and line-height will tighten the gradient background around H1. Below is what I tested and found to look most like your Photoshop example.

```
.header-text h1{
background: 
linear-gradient(
  rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7),
  rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.7)
);
position: absolute;
font-weight: normal;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
font-family: 'Roboto', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 75px;
color: #f2f2f2;
width: 900px;
height: auto;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
line-height:48px; 
}
```

[image: Screenshot of tested CSS]